# JP QL - Filtering result in a One To Many relationship

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpql

I am stuck trying to construct a JPQL query and was hoping someone with more JPA experience than mine could help. Consider the following two entities:

```
class Author{
  String name
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="author")
  Set<Book> books
}

class Book{
  String title  
  Boolean inPrint
  @ManyToOne
  Author author
}
```

If I want to return a specific Author (by name) and eagerly fetch (ie LEFT JOIN FETCH) the books where the Book.inPrint flag is true, how would I express that in JPQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a FROM Author a LEFT JOIN a.books b WHERE b.inPrint = true OR b is null
```

Comment: This will return the correct list of authors, but for the authors that match, all books will be retrieved, also those with inPrint = false. Hibernate would execute the join fetch variant of this query happily, but it's a violation of the JPQL-spec. Sometimes it's enough to turn the query around : select b from Book b left join a.author a where ... that way you only get what you want, but authors with more than one matching book will be duplicated.