# How to filter parent object which has list of children and a child has list of grand children and by matching property of grand children

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Object hierarchy is as follow.

CoverCategory has multiple Covers and a Cover has multiple SubCovers.
Let says that in coding

## CoverCategory

```
@Entity
public class CoverCategory {

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToMany
List<Cover> coverList;

}
```

## Cover

```
@Entity
public class Cover {

 @Id
 private Long id;

 @ManyToOne
 private CoverCategory coverCategory;

 @OneToMany
 private List<SubCover> subCoverList;

}
```

## Sub Cover

```
@Entity
public class SubCover {

       @Id
       private Long id;

       @ManyToOne
       private Cover cover;

       private String name;
}
```

Here what I am try to do is select all the cover categories which has sub cover name "subcover1"

I tried to write the code as follows

```
String name = "subcover1";
Session session = getCurrentSession();
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CoverCategory> creteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(CoverCategory.class);
Root<CoverCategory> root = creteriaQuery.from(CoverCategory.class);
creteriaQuery.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("coverList").get("subCoverList").get("name"),name));
Query<CoverCategory> query = session.createQuery(creteriaQuery);
List<CoverCategory> results = query.getResultList();
```

But it gives me following exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.coverList] of basic type; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.coverList] of basic type
```

Can someone tell me how to do this properly. Thanks in advance.
Only need to be done in criteria builder

Comment: Try doing a `root.join("coverList")` before the `root.get("coverList")`, and the same goes for `"subCoverList"` and so on

Comment: If you're not against using JPQL instead of Criteria Queries, you can take a look at [this other example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3523429/3841161). I believe your equivalent query would be `SELECT cc FROM CoverCategory cc LEFT JOIN Cover c LEFT JOIN SubCover sc WHERE sc.name = :param`

Comment: I believe he specifically said "Only need to be done in criteria builder"

Answer (score 0):

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CoverCategory> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(CoverCategory.class);
Root<CoverCategory> root = criteriaQuery.from(CoverCategory.class);
Join<CoverCategory,Cover> coverJoin = root.join("coverList");
Join<Cover, SubCover> subjoin = coverJoin.join("subCoverList");
criteriaBuilder.equal(subjoin.get("name"),name);
Query<CoverCategory> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<CoverCategory> results = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to why this answer solves the problem and is a good solution. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer